# laravel7, is there mindmap for login process?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

- I am creating my first package with Laravel 7.
- Idea is make login and register process inside it.
- Login and Register forms are working,
- and process logic work aswell.
- When I am calling them from route-file directly Blade form.
- But
- I have added login and register controller.
- After login form send request to logged in,
- comes issues:

Issue 1) Trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`
not found.

- Tried so far:
- added `"laravel/ui"` to Composer.json inside my package.

---- Edit ---

- I found "illuminate/auth" from  Github/Laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/illuminate/Auth/composer.json
- namespace is same as error.
- installed but still same error.

---

Q) Do I miss some other package which calls User trait ?

Thanks Mika.

--- EDIT ----
I have been searcing few days to way to do it.
Found https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/create-laravel-route-inside-another-composer-packages

- But it is for Larave 5.X, is it still valid way to fix this problem ?

---

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers are used in app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php, if your controller not extending that controller you should import the trait

Comment: Inside my package,  my LoginController extends BaseController,  which is in
MyPackage\Core\Controllers\Controller.php. --> which extends Laravel   "Illuminate\Routing\Controller.

Comment: if you are importing single package, maybe its in vendor/package folder resulting in error to the default path of dependencies, try to check your vendor folder structure

Comment: "laravel/ui" -> this is what I am adding to myPackage. File can be found from Vendor/Laravel/ui/auth-backend/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Laravel's built in authentication, this is how you set it up:

Run

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then run

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

If you want to use Vue with the UI scaffolding you can run `php artisan ui vue --auth` instead of `php artisan ui:auth`.

So I'd recommend to undo what you did (seems like you didn't run through the install steps properly) and then follow the steps above. More info in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication).

Comment: Sorry, I am doing this inside package, there is no full Laravel on it.

Answer (score 0):

The trait you're trying to use is in fact inside `laravel/ui`, so you should still require this package in your `composer.json`: https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php

I would also try running `composer dump-autoload` after installing the `laravel/ui` package (this should clear any cached autoloaders).

Also, please don't forget to properly import the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your controller:

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
...

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have added these two required package to inside myPackage composer.json:   "laravel/ui"  and "illuminate/auth"      and I am using that trait.  Error is  :  "Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers' not Found".      File can be found from Vendor/Laravel/ui/auth-backend/ folder.

Comment: if I disabled that Trait: new error is : "Call to undefined method App\User::newQuery() "
but that can be find config/auth -> 'providers' => [ 'users' => [ 'driver => 'eloquent', 'model' => MyPackage\Core\Models\User::class ]  --- why it still looking for old namespace ?